# Highcharts : Change opacity of a column chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I need change opacity of column in stack chart when using highchart. Because i need transparent

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#trend').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Weight Oscillation Projection'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['1st Week', '2nd Week', '3rd Week', '4th Week', '5th Week', '6th Week']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Weight (Kg)'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: false,                    
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false,  
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false,                        
                    }
                },                    
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],                   
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
                color: '#fff',
                style: {opacity: 0.0}  
            }]
        });
    });    
</script>
```

I know series -> data object has not property for change style. How can we do such things?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the [rgba format](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/RGBA) to change the opacity.

Example:

```
color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.50)'
```

---

*Reference*

- [Highcharts Docs chart design and style](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors)

> Semi-transparent colors in Highcharts are given in the rgba format rgba(255,255,255,1). The last parameter is the alpha or opacity that ranges from 0, fully transparent, to 1, fully opaque. Because of this, there are no separate opacity options in the Highcharts API.

Comment: Works great for line charts in a series as well. Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want the legends to have opaque colors, but the fill to have  transparent colors. For area  charts this can be done with `fillOpacity`

Answer (score 0):

You can now use this property natively available on highcharts.
[PlotOptions.Series.Opacity](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.opacity)